# What is the difference between using \u and \x while representing character literal

Tags: c#

I have seen `\u` and `\x` used interchangeably in some places while representing a character literal.

For example `'\u00A9' == '\x00A9'` evaluates to `true`

Aren't we supposed to use only `\u` to represent unicode character? What is the use of having two ways to represent a character?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend only using `\u`, as it's much less error-prone.

`\x` consumes 1-4 characters, so long as they're hex digits - whereas `\u` must *always* be followed by 4 hex digits. From the C# 5 specification, section 2.4.4.4, the grammar for `\x`:

> *hexadecimal-escape-sequence:*
>     `\x` *hex-digit* *hex-digit*<sub>opt</sub> *hex-digit*<sub>opt</sub> *hex-digit*<sub>opt</sub>

So for example:

```
string good = "Tab\x9Good compiler";
string bad =  "Tab\x9Bad compiler";
```

... look similar but are *very* different strings, as the latter is effectively "Tab" followed by `U+9BAD` followed by " compiler".

Personally I wish the C# language had never included `\x`, but there we go.

Note that there's also `\U`, which is always followed by 8 hex digits, primarily used for non-BMP characters.

There's one other big difference between `\u` and `\x`: the latter is *only* used in character and string literals, whereas `\u` can also be used in identifiers:

```
string x = "just a normal string";
Console.WriteLine(\u0078); // Still refers to the identifier x
```

Comment: Of course, this is C#, where I would expect C's quirks like this _not_ to exist. Any reason why this "quirk" was included?

Comment: Thanks Jon, using \u in identifiers was new to me :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I don't know, I'm afraid. The only annotation in the C# 4 spec around this is my own, expressing the same alarm :) I suspect it *was* for compatibility with C - a misguided aim in this case, IMO.

Comment: All other points are clear, but I am struggling to understand the purpose of your good/bad example. The output of `"Tab\x9Bad compiler"` and `"Tab\u9Bad compiler"` are same; so in this example, both are equally bad (or good) in that sense?

Comment: @vulcanraven: No, because case I'd be looking for "the four characters after \u" unconditionally. Whereas it's very easy to see "Ah, \x9 - that means tab; now, what comes after the tab?" It's all about how obvious the result is.