# What's the difference between hex code (\x) and unicode (\u) chars?

Tags: r, unicode, hex

From `?Quotes`:

> ```
> \xnn   character with given hex code (1 or 2 hex digits)  
> \unnnn Unicode character with given code (1--4 hex digits)
> ```

In the case where the Unicode character has only one or two digits, I would expect these characters to be the same.  In fact, one of the examples on the `?Quotes` help page shows:

```
"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21"
## [1] "Hello World!"
"\u48\u65\u6c\u6c\u6f\u20\u57\u6f\u72\u6c\u64\u21"
## [1] "Hello World!"
```

However, under Linux, when trying to print a pound sign, I see

```
cat("\ua3")
## £
cat("\xa3")
## �
```

That is, the `\x` hex code fails to display correctly.  (This behaviour persisted with any locale that I tried.)  Under Windows 7 both versions show a pound sign.

If I convert to integer and back then the pound sign displays correctly under Linux.

```
cat(intToUtf8(utf8ToInt("\xa3")))
## £
```

Incidentally, this doesn't work under Windows, since `utf8ToInt("\xa3")` returns `NA`.

Some `\x` characters return `NA` under Windows but throw an error under Linux.  For example:

```
utf8ToInt("\xf0")
## Error in utf8ToInt("\xf0") : invalid UTF-8 string
```

(`"\uf0"` is a valid character.)

These examples show that there are some differences between `\x` and `\u` forms of characters, which seem to be OS-specific, but I can't see any logic in how they are defined.

What are the difference between these two character forms?

Comment: That's C# but it may help you as it is the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175482/what-is-the-difference-between-using-u-and-x-while-representing-character-lite

Comment: @etienne I wouldn't be surprised if a detailed wiki answer from Richie himself will follow in short.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: nah, he just tweeted this question, so he must be stumped. :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Yep, completely stumped.  I suspect that the two things are meant to be the same, and that these quirks are bugs, but I thought I'd ask you good folks before ranting at R-core.

Comment: @etienne Thanks; though it looks like the C# interpretations of `\x` and `\u` are slightly different in R.

Comment: I think charToRaw will help you puzzle this out

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The escape sequence `\xNN` inserts the raw byte `NN` into a string, whereas `\uNN` inserts the UTF-8 bytes for the Unicode code point `NN` into a UTF-8 string:

```
> charToRaw('\xA3')
[1] a3
> charToRaw('\uA3')
[1] c2 a3
```

These two types of escape sequence cannot be mixed in the same string:

```
> '\ua3\xa3'
Error: mixing Unicode and octal/hex escapes in a string is not allowed
```

This is because the escape sequences also define the *encoding* of the string. A `\uNN` sequence explicitly sets the encoding of the entire string to "UTF-8", whereas `\xNN` leaves it in the default "unknown" (aka. native) encoding:

```
> Encoding('\xa3')
[1] "unknown"
> Encoding('\ua3')
[1] "UTF-8"
```

This becomes important when printing strings, as they need to be converted into the appropriate output encoding (e.g., that of your console). Strings with a defined encoding can be converted appropriately (see `enc2native`), but those with an "unknown" encoding are simply output as-is:

- On Linux, your console is probably expecting UTF-8 text, and as `0xA3` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, it gives you "�".
- On Windows, your console is probably expecting Windows-1252 text, and as `0xA3` is the correct encoding for "£", that's what you see. (When the string is `\uA3`, a conversion from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 takes place.)

If the encoding is set explicitly, the appropriate conversion will take place on Linux:

```
> s <- '\xa3'
> Encoding(s) <- 'latin1'
> cat(s)
£
```