# RStudio - Weird characters becoming regular characters

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I'm working with a messy database, in which I need to give format to some columns of data. For this, I use a lot of GSub and other forms of regular expressions. My problem is some of the characters I need to clean are "weird" characters, specially the A with the curly thing above followed by other weird character (Ã‘).

When I copy from the database and then paste on my gsub function:

`gsub("CALLÃ‘E", "CALLE", data)`

[image]

It works fine until I close and RStudio and reopen it. Then the characters are different in the RScript file. It is as if RStudio didn't support weird characters itself, and removes them from the Scripts when they are reopened:

`gsub("CALLÃ'E", "CALLE", data)`

[image]

How can I avoid this? And keep my weird characters even after closing the file.

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34317869/3079302) helps. PS: when you edit your question to make corrections, you may as well remove what was wrong, if it does not provide any context nor does change  the question itself.

Comment: For simplicity, I'm doing this:   (1)vector<-c('CALLÃ‘E')  (2) Encoding(vector)<-'latin1'  but the Vector remains the same.

Comment: Why are you saying latin1 if you want to keep non latin characters?

Comment: Still, the problem is not with the Data itself. I know fixing the data could lead to another solution.... But I wonder why is RStudio changing the characters in my RScript file from "weird" to that red dot.

Comment: Your explanation of the situation is insufficient to see what's actually going on, but it seems to have something to do with encoding. Helpful: `?iconv`, `?stringi::stri_trans_general`

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a problem with encoding, hence I linked to that question. In that case, `latin1` was specific to the said question, I didn't mean you had to use that specific encoding. You may also want to check RStudio preferences > General > Default text encoding.

Comment: Also, please clarify what do you mean by this *When I copy from the database and then paste on my gsub function*. Are copying through a GUI front-end? What is the encoding of it? Are you doing in any other way? Please describe.

Comment: I'm copying from the View(dataframe) view given by RStudio into the RScript file. I take a look at the View(dataframe) so I know which weird characters I have to remove. So I copy them into the gsub function in the RScript file. After I close and open RStudio, the weird characters in the RScript file are different, so the function doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain this any further... What is changing is NOT the dataframe NOR the database, is the RScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RStudio, go to `File` -> `Save with Encoding...`

Select `UTF-8` option.