# How to remove non alphanumeric characters

Tags: r, regex, alphanumeric, data-cleaning

I have a text column which can contain weird characters such as:

```
"\xe2�\xe2�????????(?("
```

I want to remove only `"\xe2�\xe2�"`

I have tried `str_replace_all("\xe2�\xe2�????????(?(","[:alnum:]", " ")`
but getting the following error: `Error: mixing Unicode and octal/hex escapes in a string is not allowed`

i could see the underlying char by

`cat("\xe2") 
â`

but cant seem to remove them...Is there an efficient way how to remove these??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415388/whats-the-difference-between-hex-code-x-and-unicode-u-chars

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have looked at that but can't seem to remove these. your code also gives the same error

Comment: @Shery Is that the precise text? Did you copy/paste the exact text into the question?

Comment: There could be other lines (dataset is about 1.3 million rows). Yes I coped the code and replaced `s` with actual string

Comment: @AGore already seen that but can't see how to remove these

Comment: Assuming that you want only ASCII characters to remain,  you could try `str_replace_all(string, "[^\x01-\x7E]", "")`

Comment: It seems you just need to set the correct encoding to read the data in correctly.

Comment: @G5W same error as mine.