# QT Not Recognizing UTF-8 Encoding, works in every other place

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

We just changed over from QT4 to QT5, we still have to account for using QT4 in some places. I am trying to correct the symbols that are showing up as question marks in boxes.

I have tried using QString and using the fromUTF8() function, which has been unsuccessful.

The section of code I am using that works in every other place looks like this.

This is using C++.

```
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
const ColumnType ColumnType::OtherNamespace = "ColumnTitle (""\xc2\xb5""s)";
#else
const ColumnType ColumnType::OtherNamespace = "ColumnTitle (""\xb5""s)";
#endif
```

I expect to get a mu (μ), but I got a question mark in a box.

What am I doing wrong? The macro for QT version check works in every other place.

Comment: If anything, I'd try `QString::fromUtf8()`, but it's hard to tell since we have no idea what is `ColumnType::OtherNamespace`'s type

Comment: I tried that and got a datatype mismatch. Need it to be a string. Unless I did it wrong, QString::fromUtf8("\xc2\xb5")

Comment: What? This function returns a QString.

Comment: I need QString (which is utf-16) to be a std::string. It's just to put some text in the header of a column

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you wrote what you wanted in the question. You did not provide any context (e.g. what is `ColumnType::OtherNamespace`'s type) and it's natural to assume QString when you're using Qt. Try `QString::fromUtf8("blah").toStdString()`.

Comment: That produced the following: "error: conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to non-scalar type"

Comment: I thought unicode encoding was "\u00b5" not "\xb5"  is the \x a different form?  Because I get question mark with \x5 version and mu with the \u.

Comment: ColumnType is a QString

Comment: Then how are you getting type mismatch when using QString::fromUtf8? It does return QString.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I am getting an error with the parameter when trying QString::fromUtf8("\xc2\xb5")

Comment: @Demolishun its the UTF-8 encoding. The problem stems from QT4 accepting a nibble from the byte and QT5 wanting the whole byte

Comment: Please, edit your question to include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's very unclear what the problem is from the above (the datatypes involved are not clear). Detail the encoding of your source file, your compiler, exact Qt versions used, and so on.

Comment: A simple, often overlooked, issue is that you're using a const char string from a source file which can have its own encoding. If you are coming from older Windows editors, new text files can be set to ascii, which are then versioned and are never updated. This same situation happened to me when switching projects from 4->5

Comment: Please provide a minimal program that illustrates the problem that we can compile and test.  Not knowing what ColumnType is or does prevents us from helping you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution turned out to be the code I wrote replaced the μ and caused an issue in a separate file that replaced the μ with the encoding. So I inserted the macro to that file and they were fixed. Thanks to everyone who suggested solutions and tried to help on limited data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QChar()` Unicode constructor instead. Here's an example with a `mu` symbol:

`QString str = QString("Here comes the mu: ") + QChar(0xb5);`

Comment: This produced an error: "ambiguous overload for 'operator+'"

Comment: What Qt version are you using? I can't reproduce it. Try wrapping the `QChar()` in QString(), like this: `+ QString(QChar(0xb5))`

Comment: Both 4 and 5. Some common files need to be made usable for both versions

Comment: I tried and got "error: conversion from 'QString' to non-scalar type"

Comment: So it's type mismatch between your ColumnType and QString. Didn't you say that ColumnType was QString?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415388/whats-the-difference-between-hex-code-x-and-unicode-u-chars)

I also found this works:

```
QString teststr2 = "\u00b5";
```

This does not:

```
QString teststr1 = "\xb5";
```

My guess is it is because it is a string literal and support for non latin/ascii characters it compiler dependent.  Have seen all sorts of these issues with other character sets as well.

**Edit:**

To add to this I played around with the "from" functions of QString.  I found a surprising thing.  If I use fromLatin1 to convert "\xb5" then it works.  If I use fromUtf8 it fails.  I am not sure what to make of this.  I know on my Linux system the default encoding for my source code is Utf8 as that is the system encoding.  That is what Qt Creator uses for encoding is the default system encoding, unless you change that.

```
QString teststr1 = "\xb5";
QString teststr2 = "\u00b5";
QString teststr3 = QString().fromLatin1("\xb5");
QString teststr4 = QString().fromUtf8("\xb5");
qInfo() << teststr1;
qInfo() << teststr2;
qInfo() << teststr3;
qInfo() << teststr4;
```

This codes outputs:

```
"�"
"µ"
"µ"
"�"
```

**Edit again:**

The '\x' escape sequence is not for unicode.  It is for specifying an arbitrary byte value in hex.  It depends upon the character encoding of the compiler and/or the file fed to the compiler if this will translate to a unicode character or not.  So using '\u' in the future will help prevent character encoding issues.  If the issue is not a font problem then it is most likely a problem with how your code treats the resulting string.  I think you have multiple issues working against you on this one.  Some of those issues we cannot help you with because your code sample is lacking.  My guess is that when you compiled it under Qt4 the string was being seen as latin1 or similar encoding.  Now in Qt5 it is seeing the string as unicode and appropriately not seeing \xb5 as unicode character anymore.

[Escape Sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

**Edit more:**

[Latin1 Encoding](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aepu)

Latin1 encoding defines micro sign as hex B5.  That is why it worked before and fails now.

Comment: I rebuilt and tried this. I got the same question mark in a box result

Comment: This could be a font problem then, that could happen if the font does not have an entry for this code point I think.