# How to display superscript text in C# Console application?

Tags: c#

I want to display superscript 3 in console application. I've tried the following methods but none of them works.

```
Console.WriteLine("\xB3");
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704169/how-to-write-superscript-in-a-string-and-display-using-messagebox-show))

`Console.WriteLine("³");` // Copied from charmap.exe and also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

How can I display it?

Comment: This also depends on the terminal...

Comment: But I've copied superscript 2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704169/how-to-write-superscript-in-a-string-and-display-using-messagebox-show) and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the *encoding* of your console is appropriate for rendering the character that you are trying to output.

The relevant property is `Console.OutputEncoding`.

See [MSDN: Console.OutputEncoding Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

0xB3 is a superscript 3 in Unicode, so you need to select `UnicodeEncoding`.

See [MSDN: UnicodeEncoding Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is displaying fine for 2 but not for 3. `Console.WriteLine("{0}\xB2 = {1}", i, i * i);` is displaying **1² = 1
2² = 4** but `Console.WriteLine("{0}\xB3 = {1}", i, i * i * i);` is displaying **13 = 1
23 = 8**

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175482/what-is-the-difference-between-using-u-and-x-while-representing-character-lite

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts. for 4 and higher you need to use \u207 before your number. So, for 2^4 you would do: Console.WriteLine("2\u2074");

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.Write("2\xB3");
```

Output:

```
2³
```