# How to show exponents under String.Format?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How do I show a to the power 2 in the string.format?

```
analysis = String.Format("\nFormula: a^2 + b^2 = c^2");
```

Instead of a^2, I would like to show the same way as shown on the HTML page.

```html
<strong>Formula: a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup></strong>
```

Comment: That's not how string.format works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display superscript text in C# Console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551716/how-to-display-superscript-text-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: may I suggest using string interpolation which was introduced in c# 6, much easier to use than string.format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Format doesn't support converting characters to superscript.  You'll need to find the correct characters yourself and pass *those* to String.Format.

[See this answer for ways to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060668/how-to-format-numbers-in-scientific-notation-with-powers-in-superscript)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. Here is the code analysis = String.Format("Formula: a" + "\xB2" + "+ b" + "\xB2" + " = c" + "\xB2");